# asyncio.lock in a Tornado application

Tags: python, locking, tornado, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a asynchronous method for use in a Tornado application. My method needs to manage a connection that can and should be shared among other calls to the function The connection is created by `await`ing. To manage this, I was using `asyncio.Lock`. However, every call to my method would hang waiting for the lock.

After a few hours of experimenting, I found out a few things,

1. If nothing `await`s in the lock block, everything works as expected
2. `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.configure('tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop')` does not help
3. `tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOMainLoop().install()` allows it to work, regardless if the event loop is started with `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()` or `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()`

Here is some sample code that wont work until unless you uncomment `AsyncIOMainLoop().install()`:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import tornado.httpclient
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
import asyncio
import tornado.locks


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    _lock = asyncio.Lock()
    #_lock = tornado.locks.Lock()

    async def get(self):
        print("in get")
        r = await tornado.gen.multi([self.foo(str(i)) for i in range(2)])
        self.write('\n'.join(r))

    async def foo(self, i):
        print("Getting first lock on " + i)
        async with self._lock:
            print("Got first lock on " + i)
            # Do something sensitive that awaits
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
        print("Unlocked on " + i)

        # Do some work
        print("Work on " + i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

        print("Getting second lock on " + i)
        async with self._lock:
            print("Got second lock on " + i)
            # Do something sensitive that doesnt await
            pass
        print("Unlocked on " + i)
        return "done"


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #AsyncIOMainLoop().install()  # This will make it work
    #tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.configure('tornado.platform.asyncio.AsyncIOLoop')  # Does not help
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    print('starting app')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I now know that `tornado.locks.Lock()` exists and works, but I'm curious why the `asyncio.Lock` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Tornado and asyncio have a global singleton event loop which everything else depends on (for advanced use cases you can avoid the singleton, but using it is idiomatic). To use both libraries together, the two singletons need to be aware of each other.

`AsyncIOMainLoop().install()` makes a Tornado event loop that points to the asyncio singleton, then sets it as the tornado singleton. This works.

`IOLoop.configure('AsyncIOLoop')` tells Tornado "whenever you need an IOLoop, create a new (non-singleton!) asyncio event loop and use that. The asyncio loop becomes the singleton when the IOLoop is started. This *almost* works, but when the `MainHandler` class is defined (and creates its class-scoped `asyncio.Lock`, the asyncio singleton is still pointing to the default (which will be replaced by the one created by AsyncIOLoop).

TL;DR: Use AsyncIOMainLoop, not AsyncIOLoop, unless you're attempting to use the more advanced non-singleton use patterns. This will get simpler in Tornado 5.0 as asyncio integration will be enabled by default.